# Preview selected image in img element under same parent as input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have couple of div's with input type file in those div. I made the input element hidden using css and made div onclick to input click. So if anyone clicks on the div, it actually clicks on the file selector. I've searched many websites and stackoverflow, tried to follow the instructions to show a preview before uploading but it seems it's not working for me or I made a mistake(browser console doesn't show error). Would you guys please help me figure out what problem I made? Thanks

```js
  jQuery( document ).ready(function($) { 

let uploaders_divs = document.getElementsByClassName("each_angle_wrapper");
 Object.entries(uploaders_divs).map(( object ) => {
  
  
  object[1].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
$( this ).find( ".file_upload" ).click();

});

});




let uploaders = document.getElementsByClassName("file_upload");
 Object.entries(uploaders).map(( object1 ) => {
  
object1[1].addEventListener('change', function (e) {
 var selector = $(this);
 if (selector.files && selector.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            selector.parent().find( "img" ).attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(selector.files[0]);
    }
 
});
});





});
```

```css
.each_angle_wrapper {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 height: 350px;
 margin-right: 35px;
}
 .each_angle_wrapper img {
max-width: 400px;
}
.file_upload {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="each_angle_wrapper">
 First Picture: <br>
 <input type="file" class="file_upload" id="first_pic_ext" name="pic1" accept="image/*"/>
 <img src="https://app.wizpi360.com/assets/img/Inventory/Editor/img_up.png" />
 </div>
 


   <div class="each_angle_wrapper">
 Second Picture:<br>
 <input type="file" class="file_upload" id="second_pic_ext" name="pic2" accept="image/*"/>
 <img src="https://app.wizpi360.com/assets/img/Inventory/Editor/img_up.png" />
 </div>
```

Comment: A quick look at your code and can already tell your `this` variable is out of scope. Do `var selector = $(this);` as the first line inside your event listener. Then instead of using `$(this)`, replace with `selector`, as in `selector.parent()...`.

Comment: doesn't work, tried without var too, doesn't work either. @JM-AGMS

Comment: You need `var selector...` code just inside `addEventListener`, and you need to replace all `$(this)` with `selector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decide to make this the answer since there a quite a few things wrong. But that's okay! We're all here to learn. I removed pure JS code since we are already using jQuery and its easier to use. Below is the code after we use jQuery to make the event listeners, complete with comments to help you understand what's happening.

The below code should work for you.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
  // creates a click event listener on all the images
  $('.each_angle_wrapper img').click(function() {
    // clicks on the respective input
    $(this).parent().find('input').click();
  });
  // creates an onchange event listener for all the inputs
  $('.file_upload').change(function() {
    // holds scope for this input
    var selector = $(this);
    // selector[0] references the direct element without jQuery since we need to access the files object inside of it
    if (selector[0].files && selector[0].files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        selector.parent().find( "img" ).attr('src', e.target.result);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(selector[0].files[0]);
    }   
  });
});
```

Comment: in the begining, I tried $('.each_angle_wrapper').addEventListener('click', function (e) { ... but it didn't work, I had to use pure JS. (JS is really complicated to me, I mostly work with php, backend developer). but your code seems to be working! Thank you a lot! Helped me reduce stress. Thanks again

Comment: Yeah, it takes some getting used to. Just like any other programming language, there are so many ways to do one thing and it can get confusing pretty quickly. Glad I can help. Good luck with your future endeavours.